# How to constrain dtw from dtw-python library?

Tags: dtw

Here is what I want to do:

- keep a reference curve unchanged (only shift and stretch a query curve)
- constrain how many elements are duplicated
- keep both start and end open

I tried:

```
dtw(ref_curve,query_curve,step_pattern=asymmetric,open_end=True,open_begin=True)
```

but I cannot constrain how the query curve is stretched

```
dtw(ref_curve,query_curve,step_pattern=mvmStepPattern(10))
```

it didn’t do anything to the curves!

```
dtw(ref_curve,query_curve,step_pattern=rabinerJuangStepPattern(4, "c"),open_end=True, open_begin=True)
```

I liked this one the most but in some cases it shifts the query curve more than needed...

I read the paper (https://www.jstatsoft.org/article/view/v031i07) and the API but still don't quite understand how to achieve what I want. Any other options to constrain number of elements that are duplicated? I would appreciate your help!

Answer (score 0):

to clarify: we are talking about functions provided by the DTW suite packages at [dynamictimewarping.github.io](https://dynamictimewarping.github.io/). The question is in fact language-independent (and may be more suited to the Cross-validated Stack Exchange).

The pattern `rabinerJuangStepPattern(4, "c")` you have found does in fact satisfy your requirements:

1. it's asymmetric, and each step advances the reference by exactly one step
2. it's slope-limited between 1/2 and 2
3. it's type "c", so can be normalized in a way that allows open-begin and open-end

If you haven't already, check out `dtw.rabinerJuangStepPattern(4, "c").plot()`.

It goes without saying that in all cases you are getting is the optimal alignment, i.e. the one with the least accumulated distance among all allowed paths.

As an alternative, you may consider the simpler `asymmetric` recursion -- as your first attempt above -- constrained with a *global* warping window: see `dtw.window` and the `window_type` argument.  This provides constraints of a different shape (and flexible size), which might suit your specific case.

PS: edited to add that the `asymmetricP2` recursion is also similar to RJ-4c, but with a more constrained slope.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer. You are right, the question is language-agnostic I just didn't know how to refer to the suite of dtw packages..

Comment: are there any examples with window_type? i could not find any

Comment: See e.g. `example(dtwWindow.plot)`. [Also online](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/dtw/versions/1.22-3/topics/dtwWindowingFunctions)